# Diff Between instance variable and local variable in java

Tags: java

```
public class Test{
static String s="sbi";
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {

     for (int i=0;i<=5;i++){
         System.out.println(s=s+i);
     }

    }
}
in this case output is 
sbi0
sbi01
sbi012
sbi0123
sbi01234
sbi012345
```

and in this case
      public class Test{

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     String s="sbi";
     for (int i=0;i<=5;i++){
         System.out.println(s=s+i);
     }

    }
  }
```

ouput is same as previous
but when i do this
       public class Test{

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {

     for (int i=0;i<=5;i++){
         String s="sbi";
         System.out.println(s=s+i);
     }

    }
 }
output is 
sbi0
sbi1
sbi2
sbi3
sbi4
sbi5
```

my question is that how it working means when i put String s outside for loop then how it works and how it appends and when i put String s="sbi" inside for loop then it works well.Can you give me how instance and local variable works and also when String s is in for loop then it is local varibale and when it is inside main then also it is local variable so what is difference between them.I apolozise for silly question as i am newbie.Kindly provide me good concept please I will be humble to you

Comment: oh sorry replace s+1 with s=s+1 in println

Answer (score 0):

In your first and second snippets, `s` is assigned "sbi" before the loop and assigned `s+i` in each iteration of the loop.

In your last snippet `s` is assigned twice in each iteration of the loop - first it is assigned "sbi" and then it is assigned `s+i` and gets printed before being assigned "sbi" again in the next iteration. Therefore it is never assigned a String longer than 4 characters.

To highlight the difference between the two snippets that use a local variable :

The second snippet is equivalent to :

```
String s = "sbi";
{
    System.out.println(s=s+0);
}
{
    System.out.println(s=s+1);
}
{
    System.out.println(s=s+2);
}
{
    System.out.println(s=s+3);
}
{
    System.out.println(s=s+4);
}
{
    System.out.println(s=s+5);
}
```

In each iteration, `s` is assigned a new String which is the concatenation of the previous value of `s` and the current value of `i`. Therefore, the length of `s` grows in each iteration.

On the other hand, your last snippet is equivalent to :

```
 {
     String s="sbi";
     System.out.println(s=s+0);
 }
 {
     String s="sbi";
     System.out.println(s=s+1);
 }
 {
     String s="sbi";
     System.out.println(s=s+2);
 }
 {
     String s="sbi";
     System.out.println(s=s+3);
 }
 {
     String s="sbi";
     System.out.println(s=s+4);
 }
 {
     String s="sbi";
     System.out.println(s=s+5);
 }
```

`s` is assigned "sbi" in each iteration, so the printed value is always "sbi" concatenated to the current value of `i`.

Comment: Inside the `for` loop, a *new* variable `s` is defined. The `s` from the previous `for` iteration goes out of scope. Nothing as assigned to this `s` ever after, it is GCed.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this:

```
for (int i=0;i<=5;i++){
         String s="sbi";
         System.out.println(s=s+i);
     }
```

**you are creating a new variable String s for every iteration in the loop**, so appending the value on s is not as such, instead you are just overwriting the value and assigning it the step in the i variable

That is the main difference between both...

Comment: Actually, no value is overwritten since `s` is a *new* variable in every iteration. The `s` from the previous iteration goes out of scope and is GCed.

Comment: s=s+i is an overwrite action on s

Comment: But that `s=s+i` is not important. The main question is about the scope of `s`.

Answer (score 0):

In your second code snippet, this line

```
String s="sbi";
```

is executed *every time again*. `s` is *local*  to the for loop and redefined in every new iteration.

In your first example, it is kept over iterations.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you give me how instance and local variable works and also when String s is in for loop then it is local varibale and when it is inside main then also it is local variable so what is difference between them

The reason your last example is giving you an output of

```
sbi0
sbi1
sbi2
sbi3
sbi4
sbi5
```

is because you are ***resetting*** String `s` value to "sbi" at the beginning of every loop!

In every fresh iteration, you create a new String `s` and set its value as `"sbi"`, followed by printing value of `i`.

---

> Diff Between instance variable and local variable in java

**Instance Variables**

Instance variables are variables which belongs to an individual object.

Example:

```
//All pets have their own name 
class Pet
{
    String name;  //An instance variable
}
```

---

**Local Variables**

Local variables are variables declaed within a scope:

Example:

```
if(condition){
    int x;     //a local variable
}

//or

for(int x=0; x<100; x+=){
    int val;   //a local variable
}
```

---

**Class Variables**

You created String `s` as static:

```
static String s="sbi";
```

These are class variables. static variables are shared by all instances of the same class. It exist even before your object is created.